# Что такое есть .cd?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Что такое .cd? Для чего он нужен? Он студией генерируется? Или вручную

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Class Diagram](https://professorweb.ru/my/programs/visual-studio/level3/3_6.php)

Comment: [Class Designer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/designing-and-viewing-classes-and-types?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Дабл кликнуть на файл не пробовали?